# Update bearer token without logging out and in again using WIF

Tags: wif

Quick summary... Here's a pseudo-flow to show what I'm trying to accomplish...

Client (angular)             -> Server (webapi/WIF)
Log in with username and pwd -> Validate login credentials and return bearer token with claims
Change selected client       -> Send new bearer token with updated claims based on selected client

- When changing selected client, the existing bearer token will of course be sent, so the server can use that to know who I am and verify I can change to the selected client before generating a new bearer token to return

More detail...

I am using the default code generated by WIF to log users in and return a bearer token that is then sent with every request from my app (angular).  I call the TOKEN endpoint with my username and password, GrantResourceOwnerCredentials is called, the user is authenticated, the claims are set, and the access_token is returned.  All well and good.

Here's the scenario I don't know how to handle.  When the user is logged in, they have the claims for the default client to which they are assigned.  However, they can change the client they're accessing at any time while logged in, but each client comes with its own set of claims, meaning that the bearer token needs to be replaced with one for the selected client.

I keep thinking there's a "public string ReturnNewBearerToken(AuthenticationTicket ticket)" function somewhere that would let me get a new token and return it as a string.  But I've scoured the web and can't find anything to do this.  Everything I've seen suggests that you have to log out and log back in to update your token, which I can't believe is the case.  I can't know what client the user wants to access the app as until the log in, but once they're logged in I can't update the token?  That would be a catch 22.

So, does anyone know how to do this with WIF?

Comment: I think I may be on to something. I found this link...  
  
http://yorkporc.wordpress.com/page/2  
  
Looking at his code, I found this line...  

var tokenStr = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);  

I'm going to dig more, but this may be the magic line that lets me create the token from my new ticket and send it back from the client.  I'll update when I know for sure!

Comment: So the exact link to the article with the line showing how to protect the ticket is here... http://yorkporc.wordpress.com/2014/04/20/owin-webapi-authorization-server-bearer-provider/.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in my comments above.  The jist is that the line...

var tokenStr = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);

is what I needed to be able to return an encoded ticket as a bearer token to my angular app.

Comment: I'm looking to use Claims/WIF with Angular/Web API. I am new to Claims and there isn't much information about this.  This works with Angular/Web API?  It looks like you are using OAuth with WIF?  Are there any templates for this that can used as a reference?  I need a place to start with this.  Thanks.